# OpenCV cv2.rectangle output binary image

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have been trying to draw rectangle on a black image, us`cv2.rectangle`.Here is my code : (It is just a sample, in actual code there is a loop i.e values x2,y2,w2,h2 changes in a loop)

```
  heir = np.zeros((np.shape(image1)[0],np.shape(image1)[1]),np.uint8);
  cv2.rectangle(heir,(x2,y2),(x2+w2,y2+h2),(255,255,0),5)
  cv2.imshow("img",heir);
  cv2.waitKey()
```

It is giving the following output: 
[image: output image : heir]
Why the image is like that? Why the boundaries are not just a line a width 5. 
I have tried, but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Is this a screen capture from imshow? Is the original image *much* higher res (e.g. 5x?) so the lines are being lost as the image is downsampled to display? What happens if you do these operations on a smaller image?

Comment: Thank you for comment. No it is not that case. It is full size image . I have not done any processing (downsample or upsample). This is imwrite version

Comment: what are typical values of x2,y2,w2,h2?

Comment: When creating heir using np.zeros you create a single layer of np.uint8 as the data type - does this mean you have 8-bit pixels, how does (255,255,0) map to this when you draw the rectangles? i.e. shouldn't you use np.zeros((np.shape(image1)[0],np.shape(image1)[1],3),dtype=np.uint8) - adding the 3, using explicit named parameter)

Comment: I just want binary image. The contour should not necessarily be colored. It can be white. Actually I have done exact same thing with cv2.contours and it is giving me output. I don't know what is the problem with cv2.rectangle

Comment: The actual values are integer values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are loading the image to be tagged (draw rectangles) in grayscale, thats why when you are adding rectangles/bounding boxes the colors are being converted to grayscale.

To fix the issue, open image in "color" format. Since, you didn't included that part of code, here is the proposed solution:

```
tag_img     = cv2.imread(MYIMAGE,1)
```

Pay attention to the second parameter here, which is "1" and means load image as color. Read more about reading images here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html

Answer (score 2):

Can't post this in a comment, but it's a negative answer: the same operations work for me on Windows/python 2.7.8/opencv3.1

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

heir = np.zeros((100,200),np.uint8);
x2=10
y2=20
w2=30
h2=40
cv2.rectangle(heir,(x2,y2),(x2+w2,y2+h2),(255,255,0),5)
cv2.imshow("img",heir);
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Comment: So why are you using cyan-ish (255,255,0) as the color of the rectangle? make it (255,255,255) if you want white.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with all possibilities . I make it (255,255,255), (255,255,0),(255,0,255) and simple 255. Nothing works

Comment: The answer you have given is also 2 channel. I wonder why is that happening to me

Comment: Actually the dimension I am giving is :x1 = np.int(np.ceil(x1 *np.shape(image1)[1]/700));

Comment: and what does that evaluate to?

Comment: in fact, what are the actual dimensions of your heir image?